# Finding kth smallest element in union of 2 sorted array

Tags: algorithm

I think this question was asked so many times, but still there aren't any clear solution!
Anyways, this is what I found as good answer in O(k) (possibly O(logm + logn) too). But I don't understand part, where if M_B > M_A (or other way round) we should be throwing away after elements after M_B. But here its reverse - throwing elements which are before M_B. Can anyone please explain why?

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/academic/class/15451-s01/recitations/rec03/rec03.ps

And other question is doing K/2 ... we should be doing it, but it isn't obvious to me.

[EDIT 1]

```
Example
A = [2, 9, 15, 22, 24, 25, 26, 30]
B = [1, 4, 5, 7, 18, 22, 27, 33]
k= 6

Answer is 9 (A[1])
```

Here is what I think, if I want to solve in O(Log k) ... need to throw k/2 elements each time. 
Base solution: if K < 2: return 2nd smallest element from - A[0], A[1], B[0], B[1]
else:
compare A[k/2] and B[k/2]: if A[k/2] < B[k/2]: then kth smallest element will be in A[1 ... n] and B[1 ... K/2] ... okay here I thrower k/2 (can do similar for A[k/2] > B[k/2]. so now question is next time also k index is K or k/2?

What I'm doing is right?

Comment: When you are doing the union of these 2 sorted arrays, what is the result of the union, or are you looking at one sorted block followed by another sorted block with nothing in common with the first?

Comment: lets say there aren't any repeating elements in both arrays. And "union" as in, merge sort! (Here without doing merge sort, find kth smallest)

Comment: So array 1 occurs first, followed by array 2.  Array 1 is sorted, array 2 is sorted, but the two together are not sorted, and there are no elements in common between the two.  Right?

Comment: yes, together not sorted and no common in any array

Comment: You will have better luck getting an answer to this, and it will be more useful to any future visitors, if you put the stuff you don't understand into the question itself instead of as a link to an external postscript file.

Comment: @DonRoby: Agreed.  Also to code muncher, could you list out a small example of sample data (the two arrays separately, the unioned result, and the output)?  It would be good if the two arrays had some elements in common so it's explicitly clear what's done with duplicates.

Comment: @DonRoby right, just edited.

Comment: @user1161318 check example too.

Comment: So A union B = [2,9,15,22,24,25,26,30,1,4,5,7,18,27,33] ?

Comment: @user1161318 it should be sorted, so [1,2,4,5,7,9,15,22 ...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That algorithm isn't bad -- it's better than the one which is usually referenced here on SO, in my opinion, because it's a lot simpler -- but it has one huge flaw: it requires that both vectors have at least `k` elements. (The problem says that they both have the same number of elements, `n`, but never specifies that `n ≥ k`; the function doesn't even let you tell it how big the vectors are. However, that's easily solved. I'll leave it as an exercise for now. In general, we'd need an algorithm like this to work on differently-sized arrays, and it does; we just need to be clear on the preconditions.)

The use of `floor` and `ceil` is nice and specific, but maybe confusing. Let's just look at this in the most general way. Also, the solution quoted seems to assume that arrays are 1-indexed (i.e. `A[1]` is the first element, not `A[0]`). The description I'm about to write, however, uses a more C-like pseudocode, so it assumes that `A[0]` is the first element. Consequently, I'm going to write it to find element `k` in the combined set, which is the `(k+1)th` element. And finally, the solution I'm about to describe differs subtly from the solution presented, which will be apparent in the end condition. IMHO, it's slightly better.

OK, if `x` is element `k` in a sequence, there are exactly `k` elements in the sequence smaller than `x`. (We won't deal with the case where there are repeated elements, but it's not much different. See note 3.)

Suppose that we know that `A` and `B` each have an element `k`. (Remember, this means they each have at least `k + 1` elements.) Select *any non-negative integer less than `k`*; we'll call it `i`. And let `j` be `k - i - 1` (so that `i + j == k - 1`). [See note 1, below.] Now, look at elements `A[i]` and `B[j]`. Let's say `A[i]` is smaller, since we just have to change all the names in the other case. Remember that we're assuming all the elements are different. So here's what we know at this point:

1) There are `i` elements in `A` which are `< A[i]`

2) There are `j` elements in `B` which are `< B[j]`

3) `A[i] < B[j]`

4) From (2) and (3), we know that:

5) There are at most `j` elements in `B` which are `< A[i]`

6) From (1) and (5), we know that:

7) There are at most `i + j` elements in `A` and `B` together which are `< A[i]`

8) But `i + j` is `k - 1`, so actually we know:

9) Element `k` of the merged array must be greater than `A[i]` (because `A[i]` is at most element `i + j`).

Since we know that the answer must be greater than `A[i]`, we can discard A[0] through A[i] (actually, we just increment an array pointer, but effectively we'll discard them). However, we've now discarded `i + 1` elements from the original problem. So out of the new set of elements (in the shortened `A` and the original `B`), we need element `k - (i + 1)`, instead of the element `k`.

Now, let's check the precondition. We said that both `A` and `B` had an element `k` elements to start with, so they both have at least `k + 1` elements. In the new problem we want to know whether the shortened `A` and the original `B` each have at least `k - i` elements. Clearly `B` does, because `k - i` is no greater `k`. Also, we removed `i + 1` elements from `A`. Originally it had at least `k + 1` elements, so now it has at least `k - i` elements. So we're OK there.

Finally, let's check the termination condition. At the beginning I said that we choose non-negative integers `i` and `j` so that `i + j == k - 1`. That's not possible if `k == 0`, but it can be done for `k == 1`. So we only need to do something special once `k` reaches 0, in which case what we need to do is return `min(A[0], B[0])`. [This is a much simpler termination condition than in the algorithm you looked at, see Note 2.]

So what's a good strategy for picking `i`? We'll end up removing either `i + 1` or `k - i` elements from the problem, and we'd like that to be as close to half of the elements as possible. So we should choose `i = floor((k - 1) / 2)`. Although it might not be immediately obvious, that will make `j = floor(k / 2)`.

I'm leaving out the bit where I solve the case where `A` and `B` have fewer elements. It's not complicated; I'd encourage you to think about it yourself.

---

[1] The algorithm you were looking at selects `i + j == k` (if `k` is even), and drops either `i` or `j` elements. Mine selects `i + j == k - 1` (always) which might make one of them smaller, but then it drops `i + 1` or `j + 1` elements. So it should converge slightly more rapidly.

[2] The difference between selecting `i + j == k` (theirs) and `i + j == k - 1` (mine) is apparent in the end condition. In their formulation, both `i` and `j` must be positive, because if one of the were 0, there is a risk of dropping 0 elements, which would be an infinite recursive loop. So in their formulation, the minimum possible value of `k` is 2, not 1, and so their termination case has to handle `k == 1`, which involves comparing between four elements, rather than two. For what it's worth, I believe the best solution of "find the second smallest element out of two sorted vectors" is: min(max(A[0], B[0]), min(A[1], B[1])), which requires three comparisons. This doesn't make their algorithm slower; just more complicated.

[3] Suppose elements could repeat. Actually this doesn't change anything. The algorithm still works. Why? Well, we could pretend that every element in `A` was actually a pair with its actual value and its actual index, and similarly for every element in `B`, and that we use the index as a tie breaker when comparing values within a vector. Between vectors, we give preference to all the elements in `A` if `A[i] ≤ B[j]`; otherwise to all the elements in `B`. This doesn't actually change the actual code at all, because we never actually have to do any comparison differently, but it makes all the inequalities in the proof valid.

Comment: Time complexity will be O(logk) or O(logm + logn)?(BTW, nice explanation +1)

Comment: It's O(log k). Neither n nor m is relevant, as long as they are greater than k.