# Getting n-sorted elements(paginated) from a list of values using Priority Queue

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, elasticsearch

I've an elasticsearch setup with some indices. My use case is to sort the  data in my application with pagination support(elastic search does sorting acorss indices, but I want to do at my end for some other reasons); My intial idea is to use priority queue(heap) to do the sorting operation.

**Scenario1 - Get 1st 100 records sorted on some filed:**
In this scenario, every elastic search index gives me it's 1st sorted 100 records and I'll push all those values to my PriorityQueue(**with maximum size of 100-page size**). Peeking the elements one-by-one should give me the 1st sorted 100 records.

**Scenario2 - Get 10th page's 100 records sorted on some filed:**
In this case, every elastic search index gives me it's sorted 1000(page size*100) records and I need to prepare the overall sorted 10th page's records from all of the indices' 1000 results. Now, my question is that can I get the desired 10th page's records by **still keeping the PriorityQueue size 100**? One naive thought is to insert elemenets into priority queue by descending order if the input sorting order is ascending, but I suppose that this thinking is logically flawed somewhere -may be not, but not able to point out precisely.

Please help.

Comment: Doesn't elastic search support sorting? Also it's worth measuring the performance of these, sorting 1000 (or 10000)  items is fast enough where you likely needn't get particularly clever.

Comment: @pvg Yeah, It does. But I want to do in my application for some other reasons.

Comment: If you're dealing with a few thousand elements, just sorting will likely be good enough for most uses. Remember your Knuth and don't _start_ with premature optimization.

Comment: @pvg Yes, I know that for smaller sets of data we need not do all these. I'm trying to solve the problem for deeper pages(for example, 1000th page). Let me know if you find any logical mistake in thought that I posted.

Comment: The question is not really clear enough to answer, it sounds like you're getting a sorted list but you want the Nth set of elements sorted on some other key?

Answer (score 1):

Leaving out the context, the algorithmic question is:

> Given a stream of elements, find the `k` "largest" elements in order.

I quote "largest" because I suspect that in context, you actually want the `k` smallest elements. That just means reversing the direction of all comparisons. However, you might want the `k` smallest elements in reverse order -- i.e. ending with the smallest element -- in which case, you need to reverse the output at the end.

If you actually need to find some page `i` of elements from the stream, then you could first find the `pagesize*i` largest elements, and then get the `pagesize` smallest elements from that subset.

As you suggest, this can be accomplished with a *minimum* priority queue `Q` of maximum size `k`:

1. For each incoming element `x`:

   - if `size(Q) < k`, Add `x` to `Q`.
   - if `x > Min(Q)`, Pop the minimum element of `Q` and then Add `x` to `Q`.
2. Sort `Q`. This is usually done by successively popping elements, because the classic priority queue `Pop` operation consists of exchanging the first and last elements of the underlying vector and then decreasing the vector size. If you continue until the priority queue part of the underlying vector is empty, the vector will consist of the elements largest to smallest (because the smallest element was the first one popped and thus is at the end of the vector).

You can make this slightly more efficient by first accumulating `k` elements into a vector, then making a heap from this vector (which becomes the priority queue) before successively handling the remaining elements as per step 1 above.

---

The above assumes that the incoming data is a single unsorted stream. However, the actual problem involves merging several already sorted streams. If you have enough memory to store all the incoming data, then there is a much better algorithm for extracting a window from the merged results, which is a generalization of the well-known algorithm for finding the k<sup>th</sup> element of the merge of two sorted lists. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13984685/1566221).

If you don't want to go to the trouble of implementing the above, you can also do it with a priority queue of input streams. To pop this priority queue, you remove the first element from the input stream at the top of the priority queue, and then downheap that input stream, based on its new first element. The downheap operation is O(m) where m is the number of streams (and also the size of the priority queue; probably a small number), and you can find the last `k` of the first `n` elements by first discarding `n - k` elements and then keeping the next `k` elements.

---

In practical terms, these may not be the best solution to your problem.

First, the fact that you want to locally sort elements which are already sorted by the server implies that the desired sortation order is different from that used by the server. In that case, the pagination is probably incorrect, and the algorithm will present inconsistent (and probably surprising) results.

Second, forcing hundreds of thousands of data elements to be transmitted over the network in order to locally select a hundred of them is a massive waste of network resources. You might not care about efficiency, but you probably should care about transmission time.

Suppose you believed that the different streams were reasonably unbiased, both in distribution and size. (That would likely be the case for sharded databases, but it may be less likely for separate searches.) In that case, you could start by requesting a window of data from each stream, roughly corresponding to the expected position of the page you are looking for. (That is, if there are `m` servers and you're looking for data elements `n-k` to `n` from the merged results, you'd expect them to be somewhere near elements `(n-k)/m` to `n/m` on each server. So you could request a window from each server covering that range. How large a window you want depends on how biased you expect the results to be.

If it turns out that the windows don't overlap, then you will need to request more data from one or more servers. However, you will then have a better idea of the distribution on each server, so you can heuristically improve your prediction for what data to request.

Eventually, this will converge to the point where your merged requests include the desired range. The efficiency of this solution really depends on the quality of the heuristics used to select the initial range requests, but in the best case it can be a lot more efficient than the brute-force requests of `n` elements from each server.

Comment: Actually, my problem statement is to find find "k sorted" elements according to the page size. I think, I've to keep the priority queue size to (pagesize*pagenumber) to get the correct results. I agree with your second point, but I've no option but sort in my application. Coming to 1st point, server is actually giving me n-sorted lists and I need to combine them and sort again- ofcourse with the same sort order used at server end.

Comment: @geekprogrammer: If you want the *last* k sorted elements, then the algorithm I present will work. If you want the last k of the first n elements, then you indeed need a priority queue of size n, but this is unlikely to be the best algorithm. (On the other hand, requesting *all* the elements when there may be millions of them might not be a great idea either.)

Comment: @geekprogrammer: ... if you want to repage locally, your best bet is probably to request all the elements once and cache them. In the cache, you can (re-)sort them. That may or may not be practical given your architecture. Although the best solution would be to do the sort and paging on the server, if at all possible.

Comment: I'm trying to solve the problem mentioned here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/pagination.html - Sorting across indices/shards. Elastic search already does it , but I need to at my end.

Comment: @geekprogrammer: That problem is real :) so you're not going to find a great solution. There are stochastic solutions based on your ability to predict how good the sharding is; if you are confident that the sharding is not (too) biased, then you can request a window of data from each shard. If the windows don't all span the desired page, you would then need to request more data from some shards, but if the sharding is unbiased, you can generally do a lot better than the naïve algorithm for deep paging. In any case, once you have the candidate data, your best bet is to quicksort it in place.

Comment: Let me corect my self; I'm not really trying to solve that problem, but trying to implement similar sorting they do while sorting across indices.  I just got a pointer that elastic sort uses priority queues to sort, but I couldn't find the complete solution.

Comment: Yeah, that definitely helps. Thank you very much for your help;appreciate it. I've upvoted the answer;I'll mark it as accepted once I understand the alternative algorithm that you have pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, it sounds like something I had to deal with in the past.  If I remember correctly, I was not able to do what I was trying to do.  If you truly cannot sort on the ElasticSearch end and have to sort on your end, and if you want pagination so you can go to arbitrary pages, then I can't think of anything else but to [gulp] download the whole index, sort, and output the correct page.

I am a little confused about the requirement of a 100 element priority queue.  It almost sounds like a homework assignment.  I don't know of any way to sort it and take the kth page like that, except maybe to create a histogram of the dimension you are sorting on and get upper and lower bounds for your sort.  Even that won't give you a perfect solution.

If anyone can think of a way to do sorting and pagination locally that does not involve downloading the whole index, or sorting and paginating with a 100 element priority queue, let me know.

Comment: you don't need to download all indices to sort across indices. Unless you want to show all the data at once. If you are going with pagination, you should only get the required data(pagesize*pagenumber) data from each index, merge the results at your appliction end, and get the relevant page results from the merged list. Please read my question carefully; you will understand it.